# Jump to and highlight characters matching regex

Tags: regular-expressions, highlighting, unicode, highlight-chars

How can I jump to the next character matching a regex (see example below)? And if possible, enable highlighting of *all* the matching characters in the buffer when I jump for the first time.

```
[^\x20-\x7eéèëê]
```

[This article](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/FindingNonAsciiCharacters) says how to do it for non-ASCII, but I want to allow certain non-ASCII characters. I tried `occur`, but it doesn't seem to accept `\x##`. Regardless, jump and highlight is highly preferable.

**Update:** To use  isearch for my purpose, I modified [this snippet](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/2754/preset-search-isearch-string-from-command-line). However, it seems to do a literal search, even if I have `t` as argument. How do I make it do a regex search?

```
(defun my-search-word ()
  (interactive)
  (isearch-forward t 1)
  (isearch-yank-string "[^ -~éèëê
]"))
```

Note: I had to include a literal newline in the search string to prevent highlighting all newlines.

Comment: `\x##` is an elisp *read syntax* escape sequence for chars and strings, so you can use it in elisp code, but you can't use it when entering a regexp *interactively*.  e.g. Interactively the regexp `[\x20]` matches any one of `\ `, `x`, `2`, and `0`.

Comment: That said, if you have `enable-recursive-minibuffers` set (preferably with `minibuffer-depth-indicate-mode` enabled) then you can use elisp evaluation to enter an interactive value. e.g. At the regexp prompt, type `C-u M-: "[^\x20-\x7eéèëê]" RET` (double-quotes included), and then you edit the double-quotes out of the result.

Answer (score 2):

During Isearch, including regexp searches, you can use `C-x 8 RET` to input any Unicode character. Completion is available against the character names, and you can alternatively enter the code point.

So you can search directly for the pattern `[^ -~éèëê]` instead of `[^\x20-\x7eéèëê]`.

You can also use character composition and input methods during Isearch, as far as I know.

These approaches let you see the characters you are searching, in the regexp pattern itself.

Comment: Do you know how to make my snippet work, so I can easily jump into this mode of searching?

Comment: Did you try using `\n` instead of a literal newline char?